# How to bind KendoUI DropDownListFor to ViewData or ViewBag?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui

I'm trying to use KendoUI DropDownListFor for my model foreignkey and bind it with ViewData/ViewBag complete list but can't seems to work, am i missing something?

```
@(Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Hotel.HotelStatusId, ViewData["HotelStatuses"] as SelectList))
```

This seems to work but required me to create a viewmodel.

```
@(Html.Kendo().DropDownListFor(model => model.Hotel.HotelStatusId)
                              .BindTo(Model.HotelStatuses)
                              .OptionLabel("select hotel status...")
                              )
```

I'm avoiding using viewmodel because i need to submit the data back to ASP MVC. With the custom viewmodel, i couldn't bind it correctly.

Comment: Does it throw exception if you cast it instead of using the AS operator?

Comment: @Pechka, no it does not cast exception.

Comment: To be honest I have no idea then

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Viewbag/ViewData can be filled like this in controller:

```
ViewData["HotelStatuses"] = 
new SelectList(db.HotelStatuses, "HotelStatusId", "HotelStatusText");
```

And in view you can use ViewData/ViewBag:

```
 @(Html.Kendo().DropDownListFor(model => model.Hotel.HotelStatusId)
 .BindTo(ViewData["HotelStatuses"] as SelectList))
 .DataTextField("Text")
```

Comment: This worked, but I had to set the DataTextField first.  .BindTo(ViewData["HotelStatuses"] as SelectList).DataTextField("Text")

Comment: I had to use `.BindTo(ViewBag.HotelStatuses)`