# MVC 5 Entity Framework 6 project with Database first, ViewBag, dropdown for foreign key and databinding

Tags: asp.net-mvc, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I am experimenting with the Entity Framework in a new mvc project, so I created a database, and started out with a database first approach. One of the tables I created had a foreign key to another table, and when the model got created, a virtual property was created to address the key value.
Then I had Visual studio create the controller / views with all the crud. Everything is working fine, but I want to change the dropdowns to Kendo.
The Controller is using ViewBag properties to send the foreign key data back to the view like so:

```
    ViewBag.CourtId = new SelectList(db.Courts, "Id", "Name", tournament.CourtId);
```

the dropdown looks like this:

```
  @Html.DropDownList("ProviderId", null, new {@class = "form-control"})<br />
```

I can't figure out how the viewBag data is being bound to the dropdown, nor have I been able to figure out how to substitiute a kendo dropdownlist?
How is this ViewBag data being bound to the dropdown?

Comment: Double check, this dropdown is not bound to any list

Comment: I am not sure what you are saying/asking? how would it be bound to a list?

Comment: The `null` you are passing in should be a list. Check with the documentation

Comment: This is the code that is auto generated by Visual Studio. When I run it, the dropdown list is populated, but I don't see how it is happening. I agree with you, I would have thought the null would have been replaced with ViewBag.CourtId, and it isn't, but it still manages to work. Just create a new project and point it at a database that has a table with a foreign key relationship, then use Visual Studio to generate the controller and views with crud. it sure would be nice if you could upload projects on this site, but I haven't seen a way to do that. Real shortcoming if you ask me.

Comment: So scouring the internet, I found a partial answer on how this is wired up: [link](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/javascript/working-with-the-dropdownlist-box-and-jquery/examining-how-aspnet-mvc-scaffolds-the-dropdownlist-helper) but I still don't see how I can get this to work with a Kendo Drop Down list.

Comment: the article states the following: "The Html.DropDownList overload shown above takes the name of the field to bind to the model. It also uses this name to look for a ViewBag object containing a SelectList object. Using this overload, you are required to name the ViewBag SelectList object GenreId. The second parameter (String.Empty) is the text to display when no item is selected. This is exactly what we want when creating a new album. If you removed the second parameter and used the following code:"

Comment: So the above sates that "It also uses the name to look for a viewbag selectlist object" Does that mean I can't just use a different control type with the same name? How does the binding code know to associate the viewbag data with the control?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so, I found the answer here: [Click this Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14108019/how-to-bind-kendoui-dropdownlistfor-to-viewdata-or-viewbag)
Just sub out:

```
    @Html.DropDownList("ProviderId", "Select a Value")
```

with

```
      @(Html.Kendo().DropDownListFor(model => model.ProviderId)
            .OptionLabel("Select a Value")
            .BindTo(ViewData["ProviderId"] as SelectList))
```